# How to remove the standart buttons shadow

Tags: android, android-button

I've button with shadow. But On Kitkat and later versions reveals the standard shadow of button . how to remove?
[image]

Comment: are you setting background to your `Button`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/app_theme_light" />
            <padding
                android:left="8dp"
                android:top="4dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/app_theme_dark" />
            <padding
                android:left="8dp"
                android:top="4dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. But I ordered  `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`  and it decided my problem... Hope this will help anybody...